# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working properly with Subtitle UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uikit

I'm creating a 2 sections `UITableView`. The first section uses `UITableViewCells` with the `Default` style, the second uses `Subtitle` style. Both cells may have a multiline text label.

I've set the table's `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

As you can see from the screenshot below, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is respected only partially when using the `Subtitle` style: the height seems to fit the `textLabel`'s height but not the `detailLabel`'s one.

How can i make a `Subtitle` cell getting the right height?

[image]

Some code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "subtitleCell")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section === 1 {
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "subtitleCell")
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = "A Long text..."
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text =  "A Long text..."
        return cell
    }
    else {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("defaultCell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = "A long text..."
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        return cell
    }

}
```

I've tried to implement a subclass of `UITableViewCell` but I many problems with autolayout and section titles (a long story), so I wonder if I could fix the issue in a simpler way.

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on `Xcode 9` and `iPhone 8 simulator`, works very well.

code is here https://github.com/williamhqs/testSubtitleCellLayout

[image]